# (Java) What is the Point of Declaring Instance Variables Private if they Can't be Referenced from Other Classes Unless they Are Static?

Tags: java, static, private, instance-variables

I understand that unless instance variables are declared private, they can be referenced and changed from other classes. I know why this can become a problem.

What I don't understand, however, is why we should declare these variables private if they can't be referenced from other classes without being declared static.

Could we accomplish the same thing by just not declaring them static?

I apologise if the answer to this question is obvious, but I have just recently begun learning the Java language and OOP in general.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't understand your question. Could you illustrate your question with code samples?

Comment: By definition, `static` variables _are not_ instance variables, because they are shared between all instances of the class.

Comment: If you don't declare them private I can make a class that is in the same package and see them from there

Comment: May be in case you want to use your parent class member in child class with getter-setter

Comment: Your question embodies several contradictions in terms.

Answer (score 0):

This is a misunderstanding. `private` and `static` don't have anything to do with each other. This would illustrate how `private` works (though that's rather ugly code - I just tried to keep things simple, please don't bash me for that):

```
class PublicAttribute{
    public Object someObject;
}

class PrivateAttribute{
    private Object someObject;
}

PublicAttribute pub = new PublicAttribute();
pub.someObject = "Hello World"; //valid

PrivateAttribute priv = new PrivateAttribute();
priv.someObject = "Hello World"; //invalid, we can't access someObject, since it's private
```

`static` on the other hand works like this:

```
class SomeObject{
    public static String staticString;
    public String notStatic;
}

SomeObject.staticString = "Hello World"; //valid
SomeObject.notStatic = "Hello World"; //invalid, we need an instance
new SomeObject().notStatic = "Hello World"; //valid, since we access the attribute of an object
```

These two nutsandbolts-tutorials should help: [access modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) and [class members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: @unknown so... do I have to understand this, or would you mind to explain what exactly you want to say? Just dumping what you currently think about isn't exactly helpful without any explanation. pancakes